# How to export multiple variables with same value in ksh?

Tags: shell, unix, ksh

I want to set the following variables to the same value in one single line

```
Example:  export A=B=C=20
```

There is a syntax available in 'bash' but how can I accomplish the above in **ksh** ?

Comment: Simply do this: export {A,B,C}=20

Answer (score 54):

Ksh93 (or bash) doesn't have such expressions, so it's better
to make it explicit. But you can bundle multiple variables
(with their initial values) in a single `export` phrase:

```
export A=1 B=2 C=3
```

Testing:

```
$ (export A=1 B=2 C=3 && ksh -c 'echo A=$A B=$B C=$C D=$D')
A=1 B=2 C=3 D=
```

---

#### Awkward alternatives

There is no C-like shortcut, unless you want this ugly thing:

```
A=${B:=${C:=1}}; echo $A $B $C
1 1 1
```

... which does not work with `export`, nor does it work when B or C are empty or non-existent.

#### Arithmetic notation

Ksh93 *arithmetic* notation **does** actually support C-style chained assignments, but for obvious reasons, this only works with numbers, and you'll then have to do the `export` separately:

```
$ ((a=b=c=d=1234))
$ echo $a $b $c $d
1234 1234 1234 1234
$ export a b d
$ ksh -c 'echo a=$a b=$b c=$c d=$d'     # Single quotes prevent immediate substitution
a=1234 b=1234 c= d=d1234                # so new ksh instance has no value for $c
```

Note how we do not export `c`, and its value in the child shell is indeed empty.

Comment: For `ksh`, certainly it works. But it is a good syntax to write an export in 2 times for other (older) shell: `var=value ; export var ;`   That to say `export a b d`is the core of the answer.

Comment: how to use syntax `export A=1 B=2 C=3` when values contains spaces?

Comment: `export A="Just use quotes"`

Answer (score 2):

Here is my example solution for this:

`$> export HTTP_PROXY=http://my.company.proxy:8080 && export http_proxy=$HTTP_PROXY https_proxy=$HTTP_PROXY HTTPS_PROXY=$HTTP_PROXY`

```
$> printenv | grep -i proxy
http_proxy=http://my.company.proxy:8080
HTTPS_PROXY=http://my.company.proxy:8080
https_proxy=http://my.company.proxy:8080
HTTP_PROXY=http://my.company.proxy:8080
```

**Explanation**

At first I set the `HTTP_PROXY` variable with `export` and execute that command and only after that (`&&` notes that) set the remaining variables to the same value as of `HTTP_PROXY`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a portable, although a bit wordy solution. The advantage over arithmetic notation is that it works also for strings:

```
$ for v in A B C D; do export $v=value; done
$ env | grep -E ^.=
_=*82496*/usr/bin/env
A=value
B=value
C=value
D=value
$ ksh --version
  version         sh (AT&T Research) 2020.0.0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
export a=60 && export b=60 && export c=60
```

May not be the best option if you have many variables

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  But, is there any 'C" equivalent of assignment in shell when exporting multiple variables

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by C equivalent..can you explain. Also if you tell what is the purpose of your question, may be I can answer better

Comment: In 'C' we can assign multiple variables to the same value  eg:  int a,b,c;  a=b=c=10;  I asked that question to group the 'variables' in '.profile' which has the same value